# Reading contents of TIB/PEB

Tags: pe

Does anyone know of a program that will display the TIB/PEB contents of a PE. I wrote a program that will read and display the TEB/PEB but I think some of the returned data is wrong.

Comment: a pe by itself does not contain any process environment block details or thread environment block details those are part of a running process  one of the tool that can display the details is cdb or windbg  C:\>cdb -c "!peb;q" calc.exe  0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '!peb;q'
PEB at 7ffd4000
    InheritedAddressSpace:    No
    ReadImageFileExecOptions: No  and a better query that states what you tried whatwent wrong and why you think it is wrong can yield better answers

Comment: Yea, I should have been more specific (a running process). Thanks for the suggestion to use windbg. It appears to do what I want.